# Synchronous content loading

Tags: javascript, jquery

Would you please help me find a way to make loading pages and elements synchronous.

I presently have:

```
$(Element).load(File);
... various unrelated commands...
window.onload = function ()
{
     Update_Elements(Class, Content);
}
```

Everything works except Update_Elements gets run prior to the load and it's changes are lost.

If I leave the load out I can see all of the updates without problems.

Where I can I use

```
$(Element).load(File, Update_Elements(Class, Content));
```

But in this situation I have conditional logic that doesn't make this possible.

Comment: Trying to get this right, I've replaced the windows.onload as above, however now it never gets called at all.

Comment: `windows` ? Is this a typo ?

Comment: Yep, thanks fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

What is this "conditional logic", and why does it make calling `Update_Elements` after `File` loads impossible?

This sequence should simply work:

1. wait for 'load' event,
2. load `File` & wait for it to complete,
3. call `Update_Elements`.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  $(Element).load(File, () => {
    Update_Elements(Class, Content);
  });
}
```

Comment: Appears from OP code that `Update_Elements()` probably returns a function based on usage shown

Comment: @charlietfl That's a reasonable assumption, but I suspect `Update_Elements()` is an executable function, and this is a bug.

Comment: I based that on `window.onload = ` expects a function. If it does return a function you can get rid of the anonymous function in the load callback

Comment: Thanks for the input.  Sometimes I call Update_Elements, sometimes I do not.  I could place all of that inside, but I usually do the original load in a separate function call as I do a lot of error checking and data handling before the actual load call.  I could just duplicate all of this in every single case where I load, so as to customize it for each code block, but I'd prefer to use a function to load the content, then later when it's loaded call my conditional content.  I do this in many different ways so hard coding it becomes a lot of copy and paste.

Comment: Would you please elaborate on the distinction between expects, returns, and anonymous function?

Comment: @ben Having to copy and paste code in several places is a sign that your code needs refactoring.

Comment: I'm presently not copying and pasting, and trying to avoid that solution as I'm worried any updates will result in code errors.  By implementing each load call inline instead of through my functions I would have to copy and paste, which I don't want to do.

Comment: @Ben There is never a situation in which you must duplicate code. You can always refactor.